# Сразу после установки Vue3 выскакивает ошибка с scss

Tags: vue.js, npm, scss, yarn

```
vue create apprtl
cd apprtl
yarn serve
```

И сходу ошибки:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error
> error  in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss
> Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

Пробовал гуглить по этим ошибкам! Грузить в chatGPT! Переустанавливать с разными версиями `node.js`, менять `npm/yarn`. Только на "голове не танцевал" разве что!

Ну не должно быть так, чтоб сразу после установки сыпались ошибки! Да ещё и решений нет нигде! Может Vue вообще не работает в России?

`App.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

@Options({
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
})
export default class App extends Vue {}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

`package.json` - пробовал устанавливать старую версию `sass-loader`

```js
{
  "name": "apprtl",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "10.1.1",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, содержимое файла ./src/App.vue

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Добавил App.vue и не понимаю, что за беда!

Comment: ```scoped lang="scss"``` если убрать, работает?

Comment: ```@Options({
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
})``` Это откуда? И зачем? Это в третьем из коробки не идёт.

Comment: И вообще, зачем вы вообще с TS начали? `vue-class-component` - это DEPRECATED.

Comment: -- Убирание scoped - не работает...
--- Из коробки установилось: @Options({   components: {     HelloWorld,   }, }) - Только установил, ничего не трогал!
---- Второй раз ставлю Vue и такая подляна (в 1-й раз работало)! vue-class-component - да фиг знает зачем)) Просто делаю тестовое в компанию!

Comment: Что-то не то вы делаете) Выбирайте при установке Composition API

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html

Comment: Установил по ссылке! Поставился vite. Но проблема та же: [plugin:vite:css] [postcss] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')... И это при том, что я не ставил никакой postcss и не собирался! Ну ладно: установил потом rollup-plugin-postcss в devDependencies и добавил в vite.config.ts... Не работает!

Comment: @VintPlanov Если вы делаете тестовое в компанию, и не можете развернуть Vue из коробки, вы точно не на ту должность идёте) `vue-cli` (команда `vue create`) с выходом vue 3 не поддерживается, и что вы там поставили - никому уже неизвестно

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar Ну уж: "взялся за зад - не говори что не рад!". Может это разрабы что-то наворотили в версии. Надо попробовать другую версию Vue, хоть времени по срокам... и желания уже нет!

Answer (score 2):

Создание проекта с Vue 3 по [инструкции](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запустить проект командой:

```
npm run dev
```

Проект поднимается со следующими параметрами:

```
  VITE v4.3.9  ready in 606 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
```

Проект поддерживает TS. В проект добавлен Vue Router, Pinia(работа со state). Установка выполнялась на Windows 11 Pro.

Версии node и npm:

```
node -v v16.19.0
npm -v 8.19.3
```

`App.vue`:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <header>
    <img alt="Vue logo" class="logo" src="@/assets/logo.svg" width="125" height="125" />

    <div class="wrapper">
      <HelloWorld msg="You did it!" />

      <nav>
        <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <RouterView />
</template>

<style scoped>
  /* Удалил для экономии места */
</style>
```

Выполните те же действия и у вас всё заработает.

Comment: Большое спасибо, за то что установил. Не запускал? 

--- Я понизил версию npm -v 8.19.3, и node v16.20.0. Установил заного по инструкции! 

--- Но ошибка осталась той же: [plugin:vite:css] [postcss] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')... 

--- E:/OSPanel/domains/test_task_for_rtl.loc/npm/project/src/assets/main.css (ПУТЬ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ)

Comment: А 3 месяца назад работало идеально! Тоже ставил vue 3.

Comment: @VintPlanov конечно запустил)! Вы приведите скрины, ваших действий. Я вижу то, что вы устанавливаете  Vue 3, а компоненты суёте второго.